# Evil: Is there a default register that does not get overwritten by later yanks to explicit registers?

Tags: evil, copy-paste, kill-ring, registers

I often use registers in `evil`, but I have a common use case that I cannot seem to resolve.  I would like to have all copied text stored somewhere that does not get overwritten when I explicitly make another copy to a specific register.

---

Here is an example:

> I want to copy this FIRST line, so I copy it (without explicitly using a register)
>
> I later realize that I want to copy this SECOND line as well, and I want to be able paste it separately from the FIRST line, so I copy it to a register (ie register `j` via `"jVy`)

I can easily paste that SECOND line (ie `"jp`), but how can I paste the FIRST line? The default register is overwritten by my second copy command (ie `"*p` would paste the SECOND line) and my clipboard stores the SECOND line as well (ie `p` would paste the SECOND line).

In sum, I don't want to explicitly use a register for all of my copy commands - that is too tedious. Is there a "default" register that I can use that is not overwritten when I copy to a specific register? Perhaps I can bind all copy commands to a specific register?

**UPDATE**

I prefer a solution that uses pure vim/evil commands, so that it is extensible for my other vim editors and vim plugins (ie JetBrains' `idea-vim`). I found my solution by using the `0` register. In my example above, I can paste the FIRST line by running `"0p`.

In hindsight, I think this solution would have been better suited for a vim-related forum, but I hope it proves helpful for other Evil-mode users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use the [`kill ring`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Ring.html).  In `evil`, your simplest option is to use `evil-paste-pop`, bound by default to `C-p`.  Here's the docstring:

> Replace the just-yanked stretch of killed text with a different stretch.
>   This command is allowed only immediatly after a `yank`,
>   `evil-paste-before`, `evil-paste-after` or `evil-paste-pop`.
>   This command uses the same paste command as before, i.e., when
>   used after `evil-paste-after` the new text is also yanked using
>   `evil-paste-after`, used with the same paste-count argument.

So:

1. Copy the first line (`yy`).
2. Copy the second line into your register (`"jyy`)
3. Paste (`p`), which pastes the second line.
4. Cycle through the kill ring with `C-p`, which will switch out your first paste (the second line) with the previous line you copied.

Comment: thanks for you answer, the `kill ring` seems very useful. In this case, I prefer a solution that keeps with the vim registers and vim keybindings. Although my questions is probably for vim than emacs related, I hope future evil-users can benefit from this post and decide which solution is most beneficial for them.

Comment: FYI, the kill ring is sufficiently useful that someone ported it to Vim as the [yank ring](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, which sticks to using the vim registers:

Just use the 0 register. In my example above, I can paste the FIRST line by running `"0p`.

Dan's kill-ring answer is also very helpful, and may be preferable for some. I prefer using the `0` register above because it keeps consistent with pure vim keybindings, which allows me to use it across other editors that support vim keybindings.

I also prefer to explicitly paste my first copy with one command, instead of cycling through all of my yanks.