# How can I remove clipboard from being the default register?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, clipboard, registers

I'm using emacs with evil keybindings (specifically spacemacs).

The default behavior of the paste command `p` is to paste in the clipboard, and default behavior of the delete command `d` is to put the removed text on the clipboard.

However, when you use vim this is not the default behavior. In vim, clipboard is on the '+' register and the default register is not in sync with the clipboard.

This has some benefits like delete commands do not overwrite your clipboard, and if you do want to overwrite the clibpoard you have to do some extra work by pressing `"+d`.

Instead of learning evil defaults, I was wondering if there is a way I can move keyboard to the '+' register. I use multiple editors with vim emulation so this minimizes friction for my workflow.

Comment: Note: [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/evil-is-there-a-default-register-that-does-not-get-overwritten-by-later-yanks-t) is related but does not answer the question of how to change the default behavior

Comment: try [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12122/how-to-access-os-clipboard-using-emacs-evil/13412#13412)